# Outlook doesn't change signature when changing "From" if new message made using mailto: or outlook.exe /c ipm.note

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I launch a new email window in Outlook using `mailto:` or using `outlook.exe /c ipm.note` and then change the "From:" to a different account, the email signature in the message doesn't change to that account's specified signature.

However, it does change as expected if I try the same thing after clicking "New Email" in Outlook.

Any thoughts on how launch the new message window differently or how to solve this otherwise?  I'm using Outlook 2016 though it may apply to other versions.